# Build, Analytics and Crash Reporting - App Center or Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

I am a bit confused as to the positioning of App Center next to the more feature rich "Azure". There seems to be a lot of crossover but I can't see why I'd ever choose App Center over Azure for:

- Build
- Analytics
- Crash Reporting
- Push Notifications

If I'm already using Azure for App Services would it not make more sense to look at Azure Monitor and Application Insights rather than Analytics and Crash Reporting in App Center?

Looking at App Center it can connect to Azure Dev Ops Repo and do "builds". Why wouldn't I stick with Azure Dev Ops for builds

I'm keen to understand what I might be missing out on by not going down the route of App Center for these things. I thought it was just the place to run automated tests on our mobile apps or to push out beta updates of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not long after posting this question I got this link suggested to me by team at App Center, 
[Choose the right service for app builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/choose-between-services)
It covers Builds and Analytics.

Which route to take for Notifications is handled by James Montemagno's [Push Notification Options for Mobile Apps](https://montemagno.com/push-notification-options-for-xamarin/)

Comment: You can Accept it as an Answer, since you work it out on your own.

Comment: Not until tomorrow :-)