# App Center + App Insights not giving me detailed error reporting from an Android crash

Tags: android, ios, azure-application-insights, visual-studio-app-center

I cannot see any detail in Application Insights when an error occurs in my mobile Android app when using App Center. My app crashed and I wanted to see how I could debug the issue. First, the crash comes in as a custom event:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Second, it has no detail to help me understand what is going on.
[image]

Finally, App Center shows the error, but it does not have any detail on the crash which might help me:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I was thinking that since my server/backend was all in Azure I should just utilize the mobile app tools as they were easy to integrate with all the backend signals, but I need more information than this. I need the whole trace.

I did not upload the symbols yet, but I'm not sure I want to make that investment of time if the end to end solution isn't going to work with this tooling. Has anybody used App Service + App Insights for detailed crash reporting?

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58505577/build-analytics-and-crash-reporting-app-center-or-azure), which seemed to be geared for App Service all up. It seems like if you're using App Center for builds + notifications + crash reporting there is a good value proposition but maybe not so deep in any one area. My concern is that I've hit the wall on App Center if I'm just using it for crash reporting for easy integration into App Services.

I want a place to see all issues in my application from mobile to server side, but it has to have detailed reporting in all of them. Should I use something else to capture mobile app crash reporting and send it to Application Insights?

I have an iOS app as well so it has to be cross platform.

**UPDATE**

Maybe there is a problem with App Center. Should this be showing me detail? Do I need symbols uploaded to see this? I sent a message to support, but even if this is resolved, I should be able to see the detail in App Insights.

[image: ![![enter image description here]

**ANOTHER UPDATE** *(side note, don't want to distract from the question but...)*

Support got back to me with this response:

> Go to App Center app > Diagnostics > then in the browser URL, changing
> the period to 28 will load the "Issues".

Which in fact does work, and it was great they were very quick to respond, but I guess this is a known issue at this point and hope this is not considered the resolution.

Still doesn't solve my push to App Insights.

Comment: Where can I find this browser url, can you help me with this